# Can't change default language in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, office365

I'm using Excel and Word in Office 365.

I've set the Language to Hebrew as my default language as you can see:

[image]

But Excel is still in English. I've restarted Excel/Word several times but still, no luck.

I'm a bit confused.

My `Office Language Preferences` is in Hebrew, so I'm not sure what's going on:

[image]

Comment: What type of language pack is Hebrew?  There are two types, only one of them, will change the interface of Office.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't see any other Hebrew packs https://gyazo.com/4ca358fa61828aa5166ef67fe778507e

Comment: To answer my own question, [Hebrew](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Language-Accessory-Pack-for-Office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f) is a full language pack, uninstall the other language packs and restart Office.

Comment: @Ramhound that's what I did before, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this thread: [Changing language of Office 365 programs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Changing-language-of-Office-365-programs/m-p/178710)

Then you need to install [Hebrew Language Accessory Pack](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: While I upvoted this, because the external link does have the appropriate information; you really should copy the relevant parts into your answer as well (as the external site may break).

Answer (score 1):

From [Change your display language and time zone in Office 365 for Business](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-your-display-language-and-time-zone-in-office-365-for-business-6f238bff-5252-441e-b32b-655d5d85d15b) (emphasis mine):

> *'Important: Some Office 365 settings, including display language, **can't be changed by users in certain Office 365 configurations**. If none of the following procedures work for you, contact your organization's Office 365 administrator for help.'*

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions, but it seems that the it explains only for Office 365 Business, while I have Office 365 Home.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling Office 365 **in Hebrew** did the trick.